# How can achieve Gmail like pinch zoom and header scrolling

Tags: android, webview, pinchzoom

How can achieve pinch zoom behavior like Gmail app? I've put header container in ScrollView followed by `WebView`. Seems It's very complex behavior.

**Here is without zoom.**

[image]

**When we pinch Webview upper container scrolled up as per zoom:**

[image]

**So far here is my initials:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></FrameLayout>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please check my answer and let me know if that helps? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

GMail uses a Chrome `WebView` with pinch zoom enabled. the zoom only applies to the single thread view. `WebSettings` [setBuiltInZoomControls()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls(boolean)) is by default `false` and [setDisplayZoomControls()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDisplayZoomControls(boolean)) is by default `true`. by changing both, the zoom works and there are no zoom controls being displayed:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

and that toolbar is a transparently styled [ActionBar](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#GeneralStyles), with style `windowActionBarOverlay` set `true`:

> Flag indicating whether this window's Action Bar should overlay application content.

---

the ActionBar's bottom shadow is being removed in the top-most scroll position. this one listens for vertical scroll events and not for any scaling gestures. this effect works about like this (initially that shadow has to be hidden):

```
webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View view, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        if(scrollY == 0) {
            /* remove the ActionBar's bottom shadow  */
        } else {
            /* apply the ActionBar's bottom shadow */
        }
    }
}
```

depending  how often the `OnScrollChangeListener` is being triggered, even checking for `scrollY == 0` and `scrollY == 1` might already suffice to switch the shadow on and off.

---

when scaling, this seems to be a `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` (see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html)), where `.getScaleFactor()` is being used to animate the secondary "toolbar" vertical top position, which then shoves it outside of the visible view-port. and this secondary "toolbar" appears to be a nested vertical `DrawerLayout` - which cannot be manually moved - that's why it moves that smooth... a `DrawerLayout` is not limited to be a horizontal drawer; and I think this is the answer.

**Edit**: I'd relatively certain now, that this is AndroidX with [MDC Motion](https://material.io/design/motion).

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. How to put header e.g. mail title container which go ways as per zoom in please check behavior on actual gmail app. I'm aware of webview built in zoom very well.

Comment: @AshishSahu I have checked the GMail app and this precisely answers your question - like it whether or not. you are probably vastly over-complicating things, which are rather simple. you'd just have to add the toolbar height as extra padding into the HTML (either server-side - or client-side with JavaScript), so that the toolbar can never cover the HTML content on load. while it should be obvious, that the HTML content should not be initially located, where the semi-transparent toolbar is. that is because both, the toolbar and the HTML content, need to start at the very top of the screen.

Comment: Toolbar is not an problem. please forgot about toolbar transparency. Problem is when user pinch webview then upper title/header should move away. I'm not sure how to explain you properly. But please ignore toolbar transparency thing.

Comment: @AshishSahu extended my answer, which is now also covering this effect. since I've used "show layout boundaries", I'm now certain that the secondary toolbar is a child of that `RelativeLayout`, and not content within the `WebView`.

Comment: the root node of that layout is even a `DrawerLayout` ...because the navigation drawer is available there. alike that secondary toolbar behaves, this is quite similar to a `DrawerLayout`'s `NavigationView`... just vertical and the position is controlled differently; but it is being shoved outside of the visible view-port in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood your question. You want to push the subject line in the upward direction and the other emails in the downward direction when an email is being expanded. I tried to implement the idea of showing an email in the Gmail app. I think I am very close to the solution as the pushing is not smooth enough. However, I wanted to share the answer here to present my thought about your question.

[I have created a GitHub repository](https://github.com/masudias/GmailView) from where you can see my implementation. I have added a readme there as well to explain the overall idea.

I tried to implement the whole thing using a `RecyclerView` have different `ViewType`s. I have added an adapter which is like the following.

```
public class RecyclerViewWithHeaderFooterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int HEADER_VIEW = 1;
    private static final int GROUPED_VIEW = 2;
    private static final int EXPANDED_VIEW = 3;

    private ArrayList<Integer> positionTracker; // Take any list that matches your requirement.
    private Context context;
    private ZoomListener zoomListener;

    // Define a constructor
    public RecyclerViewWithHeaderFooterAdapter(Context context, ZoomListener zoomListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.zoomListener = zoomListener;
        positionTracker = Utilities.populatePositionsWithDummyData();
    }

    // Define a ViewHolder for Header view
    public class HeaderViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do whatever you want on clicking the item
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Define a ViewHolder for Expanded view
    public class ExpandedViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public ExpandedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do whatever you want on clicking the item
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Define a ViewHolder for Expanded view
    public class GroupedViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public GroupedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do whatever you want on clicking the item
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // And now in onCreateViewHolder you have to pass the correct view
    // while populating the list item.
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;

        if (viewType == EXPANDED_VIEW) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_expanded, parent, false);
            ExpandedViewHolder vh = new ExpandedViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        } else if (viewType == HEADER_VIEW) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_header, parent, false);
            HeaderViewHolder vh = new HeaderViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_grouped, parent, false);
            GroupedViewHolder vh = new GroupedViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }
    }

    // Now bind the ViewHolder in onBindViewHolder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try {
            if (holder instanceof ExpandedViewHolder) {
                ExpandedViewHolder vh = (ExpandedViewHolder) holder;
                vh.bindExpandedView(position);
            } else if (holder instanceof GroupedViewHolder) {
                GroupedViewHolder vh = (GroupedViewHolder) holder;
            } else if (holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
                HeaderViewHolder vh = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Now the critical part. You have return the exact item count of your list
    // I've only one footer. So I returned data.size() + 1
    // If you've multiple headers and footers, you've to return total count
    // like, headers.size() + data.size() + footers.size()

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return DEMO_LIST_SIZE; // Let us consider we have 6 elements. This can be replaced with email chain size
    }

    // Now define getItemViewType of your own.
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (positionTracker.get(position).equals(HEADER_VIEW)) {
            // This is where we'll add the header.
            return HEADER_VIEW;
        } else if (positionTracker.get(position).equals(GROUPED_VIEW)) {
            // This is where we'll add the header.
            return GROUPED_VIEW;
        } else if (positionTracker.get(position).equals(EXPANDED_VIEW)) {
            // This is where we'll add the header.
            return EXPANDED_VIEW;
        }

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    // So you're done with adding a footer and its action on onClick.
    // Now set the default ViewHolder for NormalViewHolder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Define elements of a row here
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // Find view by ID and initialize here
        }

        public void bindExpandedView(final int position) {
            // bindExpandedView() method to implement actions
            final WebView webView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.email_details_web_view);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
            webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                    zoomListener.onZoomListener(position);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And the expanded list item contains a `WebView` which has a wrapper which is `wrap_content`. You will find the following layout in the `list_item_expanded.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/email_details_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:ignore="WebViewLayout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to add some dummy data for the experiment and hence the `Utility` class was written. The `RecyclerView` is set to have a reverse layout as this is the common expectation of showing a conversation in a `RecyclerView`.

The key idea is to `scrollToPosition` when the `WebView` is being expanded. So that it feels like the items are push upwards and downwards to accommodate the expansion. Hope you get the idea.

I am adding some screenshots here to give you an idea about what I could achieve so far.

[image]

Please note that the pushing mechanism is not smooth. I will be working on this. However, I thought I should post it here as this might help you in your thinking. I would like to suggest you [clone the repository](https://github.com/masudias/GmailView) and run the application to check the overall implementation. Let me know if there is any feedback.

Comment: this does barely appear to be related to the GMail message detail view. there are certainly two top toolbars; a sticky one for the application and a move-able one for the message. where do all these "message not expanded" items come from?

Comment: @MartinZeitler This is just a placeholder for the grouped messages. Sometimes multiple emails are chained and grouped which is being denoted by "message not expanded" list item. Clicking on this will expand the message which might have the same pinch zoom behavior. I just added a placeholder to provide you an idea that, multiple view items like Gmail app is possible. Let me know if that clears your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement this behaviour using `webview.setBuiltInZoomControls()` and `ScaleGestureDetector` by overriding `WebView` and feeding all motion events to detector. It works, but scale detector and zoom work a bit different and UX turns out to be terrible.

If you look closely at Gmail zoom implementation and a webview zoom you will see they are different. I believe the Gmail zoom is based on `view.setScaleX()` and `view.setScaleY()`. You can get a basic behaviour by subclassing `WebView` and following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale#basic-scaling-example). You may also need to call `view.setPivotX()` and `view.setPivotY()`. Gmail implementation is more complex since it has scroll and seems to scroll the content up while you zoom in. You can try to use some library that implements the zoomable container and supports scrolling, like [this one](https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout). However I was unable to make it work properly with `WebView`.

Overall it's a complex task and you have to play with the implementation yourself to make some compromises and get a similar but decent UX.